# Combine all lists(list of strings) between two empty lists into one list in Python

Tags: python, regex, list, concatenation, grouping

I want to convert all lists that are between two empty lists into one list. Example

```
    []
    ['The', 'tablets', 'are', 'filled', 'into', 'cylindrically', 'shaped', 'bottles', 'made', 'of', 'white', 'coloured']
    ['polyethylene.', 'The', 'volumes', 'of', 'the', 'bottles', 'depend', 'on', 'the', 'tablet', 'strength', 'and', 'amount', 'of']
    ['tablets,', 'ranging', 'from', '20', 'to', '175', 'ml.', 'The', 'screw', 'type', 'cap', 'is', 'made', 'of', 'white', 'coloured']
    ['polypropylene', 'and', 'is', 'equipped', 'with', 'a', 'tamper', 'proof', 'ring.']
    []
    ['PVC/PVDC', 'blister', 'pack']
    []
    ['Blisters', 'are', 'made', 'in', 'a', 'thermo-forming', 'process', 'from', 'a', 'PVC/PVDC', 'base', 'web.', 'Each', 'tablet']
    ['is', 'filled', 'into', 'a', 'separate', 'blister', 'and', 'a', 'lidding', 'foil', 'of', 'aluminium', 'is', 'welded', 'on.', 'The', 'blisters']
    ['are', 'opened', 'by', 'pressing', 'the', 'tablets', 'through', 'the', 'lidding', 'foil.', 'PVDC', 'foil', 'is', 'in', 'contact', 'with']
    ['the', 'tablets.']
    []
    ['Aluminium', 'blister', 'pack']
    []
```

From this the first list I want is:

```
['The', 'tablets', 'are', 'filled', 'into', 'cylindrically', 'shaped', 'bottles', 'made', 'of', 'white', 'coloured', 'polyethylene.', 'The', 'volumes', 'of', 'the', 'bottles', 'depend', 'on', 'the', 'tablet', 'strength', 'and', 'amount', 'of', 'tablets,', 'ranging', 'from', '20', 'to', '175', 'ml.', 'The', 'screw', 'type', 'cap', 'is', 'made', 'of', 'white', 'coloured','polypropylene', 'and', 'is', 'equipped', 'with', 'a', 'tamper', 'proof', 'ring.']
```

The next list becomes:

```
['PVC/PVDC', 'blister', 'pack']
```

and the pattern should continue.
Code till now:

```
import csv, re
filepath = r'C:\Users\techj\Music\Data\Tagged\090388 (1.0,CURRENT,LATEST APPROVED.txt)'

with open(filepath) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
#        s = ' '.join(x for x in content if x)
#        print(s)

        for line in content:
            line = line.split()
            print(line)
```

Comment: Can you show the data from file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be what you are looking for, but I think you are trying to read paragraphs from the file. This code will give you paragraphs:

```
with open(path) as f:
    data=f.read()
paragraphs=data.split("\n\n")
```

Now if you want words from each paragraph, you can split them by space:

```
all_words=[]
for paragraph in paragraphs:
    words=paragraph.split(" ")
    all_words.append(words)
print(all_words)
```

Comment: Thanks. Just need to reduce one space in the paragraph.split function

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
filepath = r'C:\Users\techj\Music\Data\Tagged\090388 (1.0,CURRENT,LATEST APPROVED.txt)'

with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
    _temp = []
    for line in file:
        _line = line.split()
        if _line:
            _temp+=_line
        else:
            print(_temp)
            _temp = []
```

For python 3.8,

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
    _temp = []
    for line in file: 
        if (_line:=line.split()):
            _temp+=_line
        else:
            print(_temp)
            _temp = []
```

Comment: @DavidBuck Check now, there was typo mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have access to your file but I wanted to test my algorithm, I created two generator functions that will produce the input lines as lists of strings. The first generator functions is based on your code reading a file and splitting each line into a list of strings. The second, which I used for testing, uses a pre-split list of list of strings. You would simply need to replace the call to `line_producer_2` with a call to `line_producer_1` to get your input from the file.

```
def line_producer_1():
    import csv, re
    filepath = r'C:\Users\techj\Music\Data\Tagged\090388 (1.0,CURRENT,LATEST APPROVED.txt)'

    with open(filepath) as f:
            content = f.readlines()
    #        s = ' '.join(x for x in content if x)
    #        print(s)

            for line in content:
                line = line.split()
                yield line

def line_producer_2():
    lines = [
        [],
        ['The', 'tablets', 'are', 'filled', 'into', 'cylindrically', 'shaped', 'bottles', 'made', 'of', 'white', 'coloured'],
        ['polyethylene.', 'The', 'volumes', 'of', 'the', 'bottles', 'depend', 'on', 'the', 'tablet', 'strength', 'and', 'amount', 'of'],
        ['tablets,', 'ranging', 'from', '20', 'to', '175', 'ml.', 'The', 'screw', 'type', 'cap', 'is', 'made', 'of', 'white', 'coloured'],
        ['polypropylene', 'and', 'is', 'equipped', 'with', 'a', 'tamper', 'proof', 'ring.'],
        [],
        ['PVC/PVDC', 'blister', 'pack'],
        [],
        ['Blisters', 'are', 'made', 'in', 'a', 'thermo-forming', 'process', 'from', 'a', 'PVC/PVDC', 'base', 'web.', 'Each', 'tablet'],
        ['is', 'filled', 'into', 'a', 'separate', 'blister', 'and', 'a', 'lidding', 'foil', 'of', 'aluminium', 'is', 'welded', 'on.', 'The', 'blisters'],
        ['are', 'opened', 'by', 'pressing', 'the', 'tablets', 'through', 'the', 'lidding', 'foil.', 'PVDC', 'foil', 'is', 'in', 'contact', 'with'],
        ['the', 'tablets.'],
        [],
        ['Aluminium', 'blister', 'pack'],
        [],
    ]
    for line in lines:
        yield line

accumulated_lines = []
for line in line_producer_2():
    if line:
        accumulated_lines.extend(line)
    elif accumulated_lines:
        print(accumulated_lines)
        accumulated_lines = []
if accumulated_lines:
    print(accumulated_lines)
```

Prints:

```
['The', 'tablets', 'are', 'filled', 'into', 'cylindrically', 'shaped', 'bottles', 'made', 'of', 'white', 'coloured', 'polyethylene.', 'The', 'volumes', 'of', 'the', 'bottles', 'depend', 'on', 'the', 'tablet', 'strength', 'and', 'amount', 'of', 'tablets,', 'ranging', 'from', '20', 'to', '175', 'ml.', 'The', 'screw', 'type', 'cap', 'is', 'made', 'of', 'white', 'coloured', 'polypropylene', 'and', 'is', 'equipped', 'with', 'a', 'tamper', 'proof', 'ring.']
['PVC/PVDC', 'blister', 'pack']
['Blisters', 'are', 'made', 'in', 'a', 'thermo-forming', 'process', 'from', 'a', 'PVC/PVDC', 'base', 'web.', 'Each', 'tablet', 'is', 'filled', 'into', 'a', 'separate', 'blister', 'and', 'a', 'lidding', 'foil', 'of', 'aluminium', 'is', 'welded', 'on.', 'The', 'blisters', 'are', 'opened', 'by', 'pressing', 'the', 'tablets', 'through', 'the', 'lidding', 'foil.', 'PVDC', 'foil', 'is', 'in', 'contact', 'with', 'the', 'tablets.']
['Aluminium', 'blister', 'pack']
```

[See Demo](https://ideone.com/Qahv17)